# VB.Net DataSet can't find table

Tags: mysql, vb.net, join, dataset

i have a problem.I should to do a join between some tables

```
sql = "select * from prodotto as p,fornitore as f,categoria as c where   
p.codice_fornitore=p.codice and p.codice_categoria=c.codice and p.codice='" & cod.Text & "'"
```

but when i can fill my dataset with the data adapter which name i should to use to refer with the result of the query.is a temporaney table with a default name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Example,

```
Private Sub FilldgvMyGrid()
   Dim SourceDataSet As New DataSet
   Dim adapter As New NpgsqlDataAdapter("select * from prodotto as p,fornitore as 
       f,categoria as c where p.codice_fornitore=p.codice and p.codice_categoria=c.codice    
       and p.codice='" & cod.Text & "'", yourSqlConn)

    adapter.Fill(SourceDataSet)
     /*if you have a Datagridview called dgvMyGrid */
    dgvMyGrid.DataSource = SourceDataSet.Tables(0)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Individual tables in a `DataSet` can be referenced by a zero-based index, so you can use `DataSet.Tables(0)` to access your result set since it appears to be the only result set in the query.